# Setting selected in dropdownlist with Angular

Tags: html, angular, html-select

I have a list displayed in a dropdownlist, but it displays the default as a blank and not as the first item in the dropdown.

I have tried adding `let i = 0` and then `[selected]="i = 0"`, but this does not seem to set the default item to the first item, however I am receiving the correct value back from `i`.

Below is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="userName">User Name</label>
    <select formControlName="userName" class="form-control" (change)="userChange($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let row of usersModel;let i = index" value="{{ row.id }}" [selected]="i == 0">{{ row.userName }} {{ i }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is my TypeScript File:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserAdminService } from '../../services/user-admin.service';
import { FormBuilder, Form, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-add-user-to-role',
  templateUrl: './add-user-to-role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-user-to-role.component.css']
})
export class AddUserToRoleComponent implements OnInit {
  addUserToRoleForm: FormGroup;
  rolesModel: any[];
  usersModel: any[];
  selectedRole: string;
  selectedUser: string;

  constructor(private userAdminService: UserAdminService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {
    var roleControl = new FormControl('');
    var userControl = new FormControl('');

    this.addUserToRoleForm = formBuilder.group({ roleName: roleControl, userName: userControl });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
this.userAdminService.getRoles().subscribe(roles => {
  this.rolesModel = roles;
  this.selectedRole = this.rolesModel[0].name;
  this.userAdminService.getUsersNotInRole(this.selectedRole).subscribe(users => {
    this.usersModel = users;
    this.selectedUser = this.usersModel[0].id;
    console.log(this.usersModel[0].userName);
    this.addUserToRoleForm.controls['roleName'].setValue(this.rolesModel[0].name);
    this.addUserToRoleForm.controls['userName'].setValue(this.usersModel[0].userName);
  });
});
  }

  userChange(event: any) {
    this.selectedUser = event.target.value;
    console.log('Selected ' + this.selectedUser);
  }

  AddUserToRole() {
    this.userAdminService.addUserToRole(this.selectedUser, this.selectedRole)
      .subscribe(result => {
        if (result.success) {
          this.router.navigate(['/roleusermaint']);
        }
        else {
          console.log('Error Received on adding user to role');
        }
      });
  }
}
```

As you can see I added `{{ i }}` in the text to make sure it shows the value of `i` and it does:

[image]

What am I missing ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I know it seems like a small problem, but adding a stackblitz with as minimal content as possible is helpful to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ah I hear you. I will check into it and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for the mention

Comment: @AxleWack, Does this help you?? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-select-option-jfuqqc .. It sets the first value to the select box.. When using reactive form, try to keep the logics in ```ts``` file..

Comment: I tried that, but does not seem to make a difference :( I have posted my `typescript` file as well

Comment: @AxleWack, I have posted it as answer .. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Axle, if you're using a Reactive Form, you needn't use `[selected]` nor `(change)`, just, when you create the form you give value to userName

Using the constructor

```
const firstId=usersModel[0].id
this.form=new FormGroup({
   userName:new FormControl(firstId)
})
```

Using formBuilder

```
const firstId=usersModel[0].id
this.form=this.fb.group({
 userName:firstId
})
```

Using setValue, after create the form

```
   const firstId=usersModel[0].id
   this.form.get('userName').setValue(firstId)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am still very new at angular, but will work through what you have provided and see how I can implement this in my existing code

Comment: @MikeS. take alook to the simple stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsqs5g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, if you change `userName:new FormControl()` by `userName:new FormControl(1)` work propertly, else not

Comment: @AxleWack, you need put the setValues:`this.addUserToRoleForm.controls['roleName'].setValue(this.selectedRole);` and `this.addUserToRoleForm.controls['userName'].setValue(this.selectedUser);` INSIDE the subscribe function

Comment: Correct you are. I have made the change and tested the value being returned with console.log, but the control is still not setting it as the default value :( I have updated my question

Comment: @Alex, take account your select's options has as value **{{row.id}}**, not **row.userName**, so you need give the id value to the control- I suppose that was an error typo, sorry- futhermore I prefer the way  `this.addUserToRoleForm.get('roleName') ` than `this.addUserToRoleForm.controls['roleName']`

Comment: You are exactly correct. I made the mistake by trying to set the value to the `name` instead of the `id` ! - What @ManirajMurugan posted is what I used, but did upvote your answer as you were very helpful and willing to help me through my typos and changes! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: But I have learnt all these from Eliseo only.. Thanks @Eliseo for your help in my questions year(s) back.. I will never forgot your help..

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Angular reactive form, try to keep the logic in `ts` file itself.

Using [**setValue()**](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value), you can set the default value to a control.

To set the default value to form control you could to it like,

```
this.form.controls['country'].setValue(this.countries[0].id)
```

In template use it like,

```
<option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
    {{ country.name }}
</option>
```

> [**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-select-option-jfuqqc)

**Ref:**

A complete sample code would be something like,

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import {Country} from './country';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  countries = [
    {
      id: 'us',
      name: 'United States'
    },
    {
      id: 'uk',
      name: 'United Kingdom'
    },
    {
      id: 'ca',
      name: 'Canada'
    }
  ];

  form: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit(){
      this.form = new FormGroup({
        country: new FormControl('')
     });
     this.form.controls['country'].setValue(this.countries[0].id)
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select formControlName="country">
        <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">
            {{ country.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```